# QGIS geometry insert on ArcGIS sde table gives st_geometry error

Tags: qgis, postgis, arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-10.5

I have created an enterprise geodatabase with ArcGIS 10.5 in a PostgreSQL 9.5 database. And I set the PostGIS template to my database. So when I create a feature class in database, I can add this layer in QGIS and I can see the data.
But when I add the data in QGIS layer that comes from database and save, it gives an error like this:

```
Could not commit changes to layer mypoints

Errors:ERROR: 1 feature(s) not added.

Provider Errors:
       PostGIS error while adding features: ERROR: column "shape" 
is of type geometry but expression is of type st_geometry
  LINE 1: ...sde"."mypoints"("shape","objectid","name") VALUES (st_geomfro...
                                          ^
HINT: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

My database keywords setted ad PG_GEOMETRY like this:

```
##PG_GEOMETRY
GEOMETRY_STORAGE    "PG_GEOMETRY"
UI_TEXT             "User Interface text description for POSTGIS geometry storage" 
END
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: "But when I add the data in QGIS and save" when you try and import a layer into the database throught QGIS? or just add the layer to the display?

Comment: Layer comes from database in QGIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, it is improper to use the `sde` login to own spatial data. The correct  procedure is to create a data ownership login (with a matching schema) to manage spatial data. Secondly, because the table is registered with ArcGIS, the rowid column may be "SDE-set", which requires special handling from non-Esri clients.

The error message indicates that the table does not use PostGIS `geometry`, but Esri `sde.st_geometry`, which is not compatible with QGIS.

The proper procedure to managing client-agnostic data in PostgreSQL is to use SQL to create the table, using the `geometry` datatype, with a `serial` datatype to auto-increment the `objectid` column. Then you can access the table from ArcGIS  through a Query Layer. The table can't be edited with Desktop, but it can be manipulated with SQL or through DA cursors.

Comment: I created another user named "gisuser" and setted privilages to geometry table. So ti does not give any error. Why sde user does not edit from QGIS?

Comment: I would be struck down by lightning if I ever tried, after telling folks not to use the sde user for twenty-two years.